# How to run a .js script only when on a certain page?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, autofill

I am new to chrome extensions so any help/advice is welcome. I would like to create an autofill chrome extension that fills in a form, only when on a certain page. How would I go about doing this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: check url and load it dynamically http://ntt.cc/2008/02/10/4-ways-to-dynamically-load-external-javascriptwith-source.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `manifest.json` file, add `a.js` as a [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) along with matches (the URLs on which this content script has to be loaded to be run in the context of the page) as follows :

```
"content_scripts": [
  {
    "matches": [
      "http://www.example.com/*",
      "http://www.example.com/pqr"
    "js": [
      "a.js"
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a content script. This stuff is covered right at the beginning of the official docs.